# Jenkins periodic build expression "*/40 * * * *" not working as expected

Tags: jenkins

[image]I used the expression "*/40 * * * *" to run jenkins job for every 40 minutes. But it is running jobs at 12:00, 12:40, 1:00, 1:40, 2:00, .....

But it is not expected. Running jobs with 20 minutes gap. Also tried "H/40 * * * *", it is also not working as expected. What is the reason and what is the correct expression?

Comment: They are working as expected. They are running after 40 minutes each hour. H/40 means each hour on a fourty minute interval . So in 12th hour it ran with 40 minut interval so in 11th hour.

Comment: @RAHULROY, Why is it running at 12:00, 1:00, 2:00.... etc.?

Comment: you are thinking about multiple hours at once hours at once. The job ran in 12th our will not have any consideration about the scheduling of the execution of 11th hour. Think of one hour at a time.  As answered by A.K . 12:00 12:40 is a valid 40 minute interval satisfying the expression. So is 13:00, 13:40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*/40 * * * *" means that you want to run it every 40 minutes within 1 hour. Therefore it runs at e.g. 12:00, 12:40, 13:00, 13:40. Since you can't fit more then one 40 minutes intervall into a single hour.

If you would have "*/20 * * * *" it would run at 12:00, 12:20, 12:40, 13:00, 13:20, ...

You would need to tell chron to run at minutes 0 and 40 for even hours, and at minute 20 for odd hours. Therefore you would need 2 cronjobs launching the same job.

**Copied from my comment**

For your example you would need

```
20 0-23/2 * * *
0,40 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23 * * *
```

This would execute your job at 13:00, 13:40, 14:20, 15:00, 15:40, etc.

Comment: @ A.K, then how to give two expressions to satisfy my requirement of running only once for every 40 minutes.

Comment: You can add multiple lines/schedules inside the "Schedule" Field.

For your case you would need "20 0-23/2 * * *" as first line and "0,40 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23 * * *" as second line